# How to change pig version while running it from a shell script?

Tags: shell, apache-pig

I am trying to run a pig script using the following shell script:

```html
pig -f scriptname.pig -param startDate=$curr_date
```

I am facing error because default pig version is 0.11.1 and my script uses some commands not compatible with this version.

How can I provide new pig version in my shell script?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have more recent pig version installed in your setting, please make sure your PIG_HOME environment valuable is pointing to the right one.